# Can anybody help to fix these haskell exercises?

Tags: haskell

> In this code the sumDaytime is not working and I do not know the problem.

```
data Temperature = Night Double | Daytime Double deriving (Eq,Show)

isDaytime :: Temperature -> Bool
isDaytime (Daytime y) = True
isDaytime (Night y) = False

countDaytime :: [Temperature] -> Double
countDaytime [] = 0.0
countDaytime (x:xs)
 | (isDaytime x) = 1.0 + (countDaytime xs)
 | otherwise = countDaytime xs


sumDaytime :: [Temperature] -> Double
sumDaytime [] = 0.0
sumDaytime (x:xs) 
 | (isDaytime x) =  x + (sumDaytime xs)  
 | otherwise = sumDaytime xs

daytimeAvg :: [Temperature] -> Double
daytimeAvg [] = 0.0
daytimeAvg x = sumDaytime x `div` countDaytime x

Example:
daytimeAvg [Night (-5), Night (-6), Daytime 0, Daytime 3, Daytime 5, Daytime 1, Night (-7)] == 2.25
daytimeAvg [Night 5, Night 0, Daytime 1, Daytime 10, Daytime 8, Daytime 5, Night 2] == 6.0
```

> This code is working, but it is only work for one Char and not for all of the chars in the string.

```
snakeToCamel :: String -> String
snakeToCamel "" = ""
snakeToCamel (x:x1:xs) 
 | x == '_' = toUpper x1 : snakeToCamel xs
 | otherwise = x:x1: snakeToCamel xs 

Example: 
snakeToCamel "apple" == "apple"
snakeToCamel "snake_to_camel" == "snakeToCamel"
snakeToCamel "snake_2_camel" == "snake2Camel"
snakeToCamel "i_am_in_snake_case" == "iAmInSnakeCase"
```

> I do not know what is the problem with my code.

```
match :: String -> String -> Maybe Char
match (x:xs) (y:ys) 
 | ' ' == y = Nothing
 | x /= y = Just x
 | x == y = match xs ys 
 | otherwise = Nothing

Example:
match "alma" "alma" == Nothing
match "alma" "asztal" == Just 'l'
match "asztal" "alma" == Just 's'
match "" "" == Nothing
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "is not working and I do not know the problem". In what way is it not working? Does it not compile? If so, do you get an error that you can share with us? Do you get an unexpected result, and if so, what result do you expect?

Comment: `div` is not defined for `Double`. It doesn't matter that all your literals *look* like `Int` or `Integer` values. They have type `Num a => a`, and when passed to a function that experts a `Double`, are interpreted as `Double` values. (That is, `Daytime` needs a `Double`, so `Daytime 0` passes the value `0 :: Double` to `Daytime`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not giving you the exact solution so you can still try to work it out on your own; however, some tips may be helpful.

Let's start with `match`: from your example I guess you want to find the first different letter in the two strings. If you try to compile your code you should get an error like this one:

```
Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
In an equation for ‘match’:
    Patterns not matched:
        [] []
        [] (_:_)
        <other patterns>
```

The compiler is trying to warn you about possible inputs you are not considering with your function: for example your program will crash if you try to call `match` with an empty string as the first argument. This is because in your code you are only performing this pattern match:

```
match (x:xs) (y:ys)
```

Meaning that both strings are considered to be not empty (since they both must have at least one char, that is `x` and `y` respectively).
I suggest you rewrite your function taking into account these simple base cases:

```
match (x:xs) "" = ... -- The second string is empty, what should you do?
match "" (y:ys) = ... -- The first string is empty
match (x:xs) (y:ys) = ... -- Both strings are not empty
    | x == y = ... -- proceed recursively
    | x /= y = ... -- you found the char you wanted!
```

Again, in `snakeToCamel` the problem is you have incomplete pattern matches: consider the possible cases

- the string is empty
- the string starts with "_" and a char
- the string falls in neither of this two categories

your function should look something like this

```
snakeToCamel :: String -> String
snakeToCamel ""         = "" -- you got this right
snakeToCamel ('_':x:xs) = toUpper x : snakeToCamel xs -- you got this right
snakeToCamel (x:xs)     = ... -- what should you do here?
```

As for `sumDaytime` it seems correct, are you sure the problem is with that function? What output are you expecting and what output does it produce, could you be more specific?

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot. I got this error massage for sumDaytime :  * Couldn't match expected type `Double'
                  with actual type `Temperature'
    * In the expression: x + (sumDaytime xs)
      In an equation for `sumDaytime':
          sumDaytime (x : xs)
            | (isDaytime x) = x + (sumDaytime xs)
            | otherwise = sumDaytime xs
    |
358 |  | (isDaytime x) = x + (sumDaytime xs)
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Vizsga.hs:358:25: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Temperature'
                  with actual type `Double'
    * In the second argument of `(+)', namely `(sumDaytime xs)'
      In the expression: x + (sumDaytime xs)
      In an equation for `sumDaytime':
          sumDaytime (x : xs)
            | (isDaytime x) = x + (sumDaytime xs)
            | otherwise = sumDaytime xs
    |
358 |  | (isDaytime x) = x + (sumDaytime xs)
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ```